# Post request returns 500 Error on Node app

Tags: node.js, heroku, google-cloud-functions, redux-toolkit, proxy-server

In my social media application, when a user comments on a post, it throws a `500 Internal Server Error.`

The console states `POST https://shielded-journey-88539.herokuapp.com/https://us-central1-myapp-1d191.cloudfunctions.net/api/post/3Y7OcHJXXXa0ilBeq35u/comment 500 (Internal Server Error)`

When I check the `commentOnPost` route on `Postman`, the response returns a `Status 200`, but the body returns `Invalid Host Header`.

[image: Postman: Comment on a Post]
[image: Postman: Body]

```
// Comment on a Post API
exports.commentOnPost = (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.body.trim() === '') {
    return res.status(400).json({ comment: 'Cannot be empty' });
    }

  const newComment = {
    body: req.body.body,
    createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
    postId: req.params.postId,
    userHandle: req.user.handle,
    profileImage: req.user.profileImage
  };

  db.doc(`/posts/${req.params.postId}`)
    .get()
    .then(doc => {
      if (!doc.exists) {
        return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Post does not exist.' });
            }
            // after gaining access to document, use prefix reference to update comment count
            return doc.ref.update({ commentCount: doc.data().commentCount + 1 })
        })
        .then(() => { // add newComment to comments collection
            return db.collection('comments').add(newComment);
        })
    .then(() => {
      res.json(newComment);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Something went wrong' });
    });
};
```

When I `console.log(commentData)` inside of `dataSlice/submitComment`, it returns just the `req.body.body` and not the rest of the `newComment` object, from the `commentOnPost` route.

[image: commentData]

```
// submitComment of dataSlice
export const submitComment = (postId, commentData) => dispatch => {
      console.log(commentData)
        return axios
        .post(`/post/${postId}/comment`, commentData)
        .then(res => {
                dispatch(submitTheComment(res.data))
          dispatch(clearErrors());
        })
        .catch(err => dispatch(setErrors(err.response)))
    };
```

I'm using my own Heroku proxy server.

```
// App.jsx
axios.defaults.baseURL =
  'https://shielded-journey-88539.herokuapp.com/https://us-central1-myapp-1d191.cloudfunctions.net/api';

// package.json
"proxy": "https://shielded-journey-88539.herokuapp.com/https://us-central1-myapp-1d191.cloudfunctions.net/api"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code, and `console.log(commentData)`, and where is `commentData`?

```
exports.commentOnPost = (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.body.trim() === '') {
    return res.status(400).json({ comment: 'Cannot be empty' });
    }
  const newComment = {
    body: req.body.body,
    createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
    postId: req.params.postId,
    userHandle: req.user.handle,
    profileImage: req.user.profileImage
  };
  
  console.log("newComment: ", newComment)

  db.doc(`/posts/${req.params.postId}`).get()
    .then(doc => {
      if (!doc.exists) {
        return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Post does not exist.' });
      }
        // after gaining access to document, use prefix reference to update comment count
        return doc.ref.update({ commentCount: doc.data().commentCount + 1 });
    }).then(() => { 
        // add newComment to comments collection
            db.collection('comments').add(newComment);
            res.status(200).json(newComment);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log("Error in Catch commentOnPost: ", err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Something went wrong' });
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, I still receive the 500 Error and am not able to see `console.log("newComment: ", newComment)` in the console. Also, `commentData` is from `dataSlice/submitComment`, which is dispatched from the `CommentForm` component. `dispatch(submitComment(postId, body))` to `submitComment = (postId, commentData)`

Comment: So what you are getting here in req: `exports.commentOnPost = (req, res) => { console.log("req: ", req)`: ...?

Comment: I create a room to fix this issue, you can join [stackoverflow Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233857/post-request-returns-500-error-on-node-app)